# Logo position on an eshop

Tags: website-design, homepage

Just a quick question; if the corporate logo is placed at the upper centre rather than on the left part of the eshop's home page, is it ok to have an info menu on the left (having the sign up, log in, search and cart on the right)

Comment: What was the reason behind moving the logo to the center?

Comment: IMHO, don't overestimate user's ability to find something on your page. Stick to the basics or you'll end up with people spending more than 10 secs to find the menu and after that, just going to another eShop.

Comment: Sure. Why not? Go for it.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!! Logo was placed at the centre mainly for brand awareness,look and feel reasons, as we are new in business.However, we are examining the possibility of having the logo on the left.Problem is we are a marketplace for handmade staff so we need to have a 'buy' and a 'sell' page giving further info.If logo is placed on the left and sign up, sign in, cart and search staff are on the right side, where should we put these two pages?Should we include them on the right as well or should we place them in the footer menu where we have all info pages on how to buy,sell andabout us?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the logo in the top left corner - people are used to it. I would not change the ecommerce UX too much - being creative is fine but remember that customers need to find what they are looking for fast. Keeping the eshop up with common standards also means that the eshop is not completely foreign to them, which makes them feel at home, which it turn may raise the conversion rate.

You can also make the top menu sticky - and add a miniature logo to it on the left side.

Try looking at some [case studies from the Baymard Institute](http://baymard.com/blog) and the [team behind visual website optimizer](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/case-studies.php) - it may help you decide.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some iconography such as a (?) to denote your info Menu.  An upper left location is not uncommon on mobile sites for a "hamburger" menu trigger.  I think one of the reasons is that it doesn't conflict with existing touch areas for the browser menu itself.  Also a mobile peek menu is better received from the left hand side.